# Can i use XNA outside visual c# on the surface rt?

Tags: c#, xna

I was wondering if and how I could use the .XNA framework outside visual c#.
Because my machine cannot use visual c#.

I'm not looking for another IDE i need to do this in notepad++. 
Windows rt is a weird case because it won't run any IDE because most of them need dlls that only the full windows has.
(windows rt is used for tablets)

If this is possible how would I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Because my machine cannot use visual c#.` Why not?

Comment: When you say `visual C#`, do you mean `C#`? Visual C# is an IDE used to create programs in the programming language C#.

Comment: No I do mean the IDE, it's because im running on a windows surface rt.

Comment: Ah ok, just wanted to make sure. (In the past I've see quite a few people mix up the two).

Comment: I know the difference i've used visual c# for quite a while now but i'm used to have an IDE, instead of notepad++.

Comment: So you're basically looking for another IDE that will allow you to use the XNA framework on you're machine?

Comment: I strongly recommend you include in your question all additional details that might help us answer your question properly and completely.

Comment: You could try using [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) (I use it as a "backup" IDE, just in case Visual Studio decides one day to not work), I'm not sure if you can build XNA projects, but still, it's worth a try.

Comment: I dont need another IDE because it wont run. I really need to do this in notepad++ only.

Comment: So you're going to write all your code using Notepad++? So what are you asking for help with?

Comment: Well how i'm going to use the XNA framework. Because the xna framework is made for visual IDE right?

Comment: Ah gotcha. When you say `use`, are you talking about for development?

Comment: Yes sorry. I can only use notepad++ for development. Not an IDE.

Comment: @TimvanOsch then I wonder if you're going to have to compile any textures or spritefonts which is supposed to be done from Visual Studio, or if you don't need them in your XNA project. Anyway, if you're not planning to solve your problem using VS, you should remove that tag from your question

Comment: XNA is dead, Microsoft no longer supports it. The XNA framework is only supported on Win7, Vista & XP. Not Win Surface.

Comment: @user1306322 It is possible to load textures without having to compile them.

Comment: @Sam really, xna is dead? :\ haven't heard about that yet. Mayve i should try to find another framework...

Comment: @TimvanOsch Yeah XNA, is [dead](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/389018/microsoft-email-confirms-plan-to-cease-xna-support/).

Comment: If I was in your position, I'd go with WPF (if it's possible).

Comment: @Sam i'd like to try that but windows rt doesnt support wpf. (i still have to confirm not sure yet). But definatly thanks for your help.

Comment: @TimvanOsch [I *think* it's suppose to work.](http://wpftutorial.net/Requirements.html) You're welcome; glad to help at anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XNA Framework Development does not function on anything except Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP.

See: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP
>
> ```
> To run XNA Framework games on a computer running a Windows operating system, you need a graphics card that supports, at minimum,
> ```
>
> Shader Model 1.1 and DirectX 9.0c. We recommend using a graphics card
>   that supports Shader Model 2.0, which is required by some samples and
>   starter kits.

I would also strongly suggest avoiding XNA for future projects as Microsoft has decided no longer to support it.

See: http://www.extremetech.com/gaming/147289-microsoft-kills-xbox-360pc-cross-platform-development-declares-directx-no-longer-evolving

Comment: It does support directx and shadermodel. And the third line says running a windows machine. But I assume i wont get any futher. Because xna is dead. And i probably wont be able to use it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @TimvanOsch, XNA Game Studio does not function on any operating systems except Vista, 7, and XP. Full stop. Windows RT is not supported and Microsoft has made no plans to do so.

Comment: Note that monogame, which was built to be a drop in replacement to Xna on other platforms does work on windows rt. Not sure if development can be done on rt itself though.